# use twitter bootstrap under a class

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I have website built with many custom css styles in some css style files.I want to use twitter bootstrap in the website.but if i include it in my pages like -

```
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css />
```

so as you can guess because of this many styles and classes overwritten by bootstrap class and styles and so is lot of problems.so if there is way i can use twitter bootstrap css and js under a class? 
I just can add my class name before every class in bootstrap.css file but that is time consuming or i go for it?? from web research i found -

```
.tw-bs {
    @import "less/bootstrap.less";
}
```

by using lesscss.org.but i did not get yet how do i compile things in my windows pc so i can use twitter bootstrap under .tw-bs class only in my site.if anyone know step by step, save my time.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing we have found is to use a separate CSS file where you deliberately overwrite some of the Bootstrap styles with what you want/need. For example, the default buttons in Bootstrap have rounded corners with a 4px radius. We decided that we wanted a more rounded look, so we put the following into a CSS file:

.btn{border-radius: 10px;}

When you reference your file AFTER the Bootstrap file it will overwrite the default Bootstrap values with yours. Sometimes the Bootstrap specificity is very hard to over-ride, in which case you'll need to style by referencing the ID of the element directly (which is more specific than classes.)

Comment: This is not what i want.i just want to use bootstrap under a class of a div as there are many styles in site  throughout many pages so adjustment with bootstrap styles quite difficult now

Comment: k i just appended my class before every class in bootstrap.css file as i got no alternative.